Spotify Web API redirect user back to the app after log out
I have a nodejs app that utilizes Spotify Web API, where I am trying to implement a log out button for the user.
Currently I am redirecting the user to
https://accounts.spotify.com/logout

which then logs the user out and eventually yields in Spotify's log out page. I wonder if it is possible to redirect user back to my app's home page after logging the user out.

There is no 'logout' endpoint in the Spotify API. The endpoint you're calling is the standard logout endpoint in the web-based UI, that's why you see the redirect to the Spotify pages, which you cannot change. There are some alternatives, such as using a new window, or an iframe. See the duplicate
